# None of these files exist

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wrote a short code, basically copy paste of a tutorial, but for some reason when I try to use another js file, it gives me an error "None of these files exist" and a list of files.

I have includes a screenshort of the enite error [image: here]

My code is just the basic structure of a React-Native app, using the blank tamplate, my only addon was the "import GoogleAuth from "./assets/code";" and ""

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import GoogleAuth from "./assets/code";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome to dogappcoolapp app</Text>
      <GoogleAuth/>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and this is is GoogleAuth.js

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';

```
function GoogleAuth(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button
            
                title ="sign up with google"

            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default GoogleAuth;
```

is [image: the explorer tab], as you can see, the path seems correct so I don't know what can cause it, as in the tutorial I watched they did nothing difference (just with different names)

Why does it happen? I could not find any solution for it on gooogle, and I even went ahead and copy pasted a tutorial and got this error.

Comment: how about `import GoogleAuth from "./assets/code/GoogleAuth.js";` since that's a file you want to import from? as opposed to a folder, which isn't a file

Comment: Gives me a different error so it's better, why does it work when in the tutorial they didn't need to add js?

Comment: Yes it works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `import GoogleAuth from "./assets/code"` you are pointing to a folder not a module/js file. It is possible if you have `index.js` there but since it is not the case you should consider replacing it with
`import GoogleAuth from "./assets/code/GoogleAuth.js"`

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing

```
import GoogleAuth from "./assets/code";
```

to

```
import GoogleAuth from "./assets/code/GoogleAuth.js";
```